# I lost my android phone, how can I recover all my Whatsapp status and messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, lost-phone

I lost my android phone (MOTO G2) on my marriage day. Now I wanted to check all my whatsapp status to write full story of my life before one year back. (In short my past time)

Is there any way to recover all the whatsapp status from another phone OR any Third party application OR any recovery option?

Please guide me! Thanks all in advance.

Comment: You lost your phone a year ago and now you have a different WhatsApp account?